# ngIf Global Service ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6

Developing a dashboard I find the following error, I understand that it is because I mishandle the Angular cycles.
I found workarounds but not a real solution.

I have a service that acts as a global scope then on the login screen when you pressed the button you updated the authenticated property to true.

The moment it becomes true I have a ngif that shows the header with the title which is stored in the global scope

From the home screen I updated the value of the title in global scope.
At that moment I get the error
ERROR Error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'FormTitle:'. Current value: 'FormTitle: Home'."

global scope:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ScopeService {
  scope: any = {
    FormTitle:"",
    showMenu:false,
    loading:false,
    authenticated:false
  };
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<div class="container-flow">
    <app-header *ngIf="ScopeService.scope.authenticated [FormTitle]="ScopeService.scope.FormTitle"></app-header>
<app-navigation *ngIf="ScopeService.scope.authenticated"></app-navigation>
<div class="main-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div> 
</div>
```

header.component.html

```html
<div class="main-header">
    <h1 class="title"> {{ FormTitle }} </h1>
</div>
```

home.commonent:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ScopeService } from '../../services/scope.service';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';
import { Router , ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup , Validators } from '@angular/forms';



@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})


export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    viewForm: FormGroup; 
  

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private ScopeService:ScopeService,
        private ApiService: ApiService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router:Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.ScopeService.scope.FormTitle = this.route.snapshot.data['title'];
    }
}
```

login click event:

```js
continuar() {
    this.ScopeService.scope.authenticated = true;
    this.router.navigate(['home'],{ skipLocationChange : true }); 
}
```